# Can we call one scenario inside another scenario in cucumber?

Tags: cucumber

I started working with behavior driven tool cucumber. Its a fun tool to use. While i was working on a problem. I came across that most of time, I am not reusing my code.

That's why I want to call a scenario from another scenario. I have searched but found nothing helpful. Can I do that ?

Another same question posted [here on github](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/237)

Comment: Not really.. but you can use "background" and "scenario outline" in features..

Comment: Ok. So i can't reuse scenarios but i can use steps. Thanks

Comment: @Ranjith's please mark this question useful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Calling-Steps-from-Step-Definitions

So there are a couple of things you can do. If you have a step you want to reuse like the following:

```
Given /^I log in as (.*)$/ do |name|
  # ...
end
```

You can call it within another step like so:

```
Given /^(.*) is logged in$/ do |name|
  step "I log in as #{name}"
end
```

You can also do the following within a step definition:

```
steps %Q{
    Given I log in as #{name}
  }
```

Comment: Ok. @Mallory Thanks for your answer. It was not exactly what i was looking for but quite smiliar

Answer (score 0):

I came to the same question - and found this post. Maybe it is on purpose that you cannot call Scenarios from other Scenarios. The framework is based on that you think about creating practical Stepdefinitions, so they can be used many times. The basis is to think before creating steps...

I created own Steps vor Login-Method, Pagetransitions to search-page or new File etc..
So in many Scenarios i reuse these Steps - and then add new ones (that can be reused, too).

Now you can think about how big one step should be. You can size it as one action in the testobject or use it as a routine to come to a certain startpoint of your Test over multiple actions. E.G. `Given Go to Startpage of creating a security request`
Java Code:

```
@Given ("^Go to Startpage of creating a security request$")
public void GoToStartpageOfCreatingASecurityRequest(){
//logic to get to the demanded point in testobject...

}
```

So as any other framework cucumber has its limits but they are intended and you have ways to work around it. ;)

Do not forget to use assertions in your test. Wether you use JUNIT or TestNG (I use TestNG). ;)